# Dynamic Combo Box parameters resetting

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, custom-controls

I've created a report control that takes a set of parameters bound to an underlying object and generates the controls using a data template selector.

```
    <local:ReportControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
        <local:ReportControl.Parameters>
            <local:ReportParameter Label="Combo Box" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsSource}" Value="{Binding [value]}"/>
            <local:ReportParameter Label="Text" Value="{Binding [text]}"/>
        </local:ReportControl.Parameters>
    </local:ReportControl>
```

The problem I have is when I used this with multiple reports selected from a dropdown list, switching between reports resets the combobox values, but not any of the other values.

A copy of a Toy application that shows the problem I'm having can be found on github [here](https://github.com/PhoenixStoneham/Combobox-usercontrol-test/tree/master) where I have a tab control with two tabs and on the first tab there is a dropdown list that shows 2 reports.

The TestViewModel class sets up the reports, and the MainWindow sets up the main UI for displaying the reports.  To simulate the fact that in the production app the reports can come from multiple locations and so have their own view attached for distinct parameter configuration, the Report Class has a ReportView object that declares the parameters as above.  Finally, the ReportControl and ReportParameter reproduces the Main report control and parameters that are added.  I've only implemented a basic freeflow text and combobox list as the parameters to prove that it's a problem with the combobox bindings.  The template selector and data type enum can also be found in ReportParameter.cs.

Would anyone have any ideas why the comboboxes are resetting, but they don't reset if the report is configured in the xaml without the additional abstraction of using a content control?  Ideas on how to fix this would also be useful.

Edit: uploaded solution to GitHub to make it easier for people to access.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve also don't link to executables it is very unsafe.

Comment: I thought I'd ensured that the executable binaries had been taken out of the solution I zipped up.  If that's not the case I'll remove any that I missed and link a new copy. - edit - I had removed all of the executeable files, and this is also the smallest amount of code that I could reproduce the issue with.

Comment: also please read the link in order to provide a good question with lots of responses. and the link is still unsafe. it is better not to use external links as much as possible.

Comment: How would I upload the solution then? As it's currently on my personal one drive

Comment: avoid uploading solution files. instead try to provide a minimal, complete and verifiable question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: The solution is the minimum complete reproduction for the issue. Some issues are more complex than can be communicated in one code file. I certainly don't know how to reduce the problem beyond what I've done there. If you do, be please let me know so that I can make it easier for myself to work out.  I've used the smallest amount of abstraction that still reproduces the issue.

Comment: I finally managed to download your source code without my antivirus getting in the way. Honestly, I think you could still make it in a one-page question. I'm looking into possible workarounds for the problem now. You see with this kind of questions you will have zero chance of finding a solution, neither it will be of any use to the website and its people. just saying.

Comment: I gave up! I suggest asking another question with **minimal possible code**. there are tons of extra codes in the attached solution which gives headache to anyone who wants to debug this mess! so please **put more effort** into asking a good question.

Comment: there are some notes though: 0. don't overcomplicate 1. do not bind view to another view (ContentControl to ReportView) use MVVM instead 2. use bindable properties 3. don't change DP metadata

Comment: How would you propose I load a dynamically loaded report into the view without using a content control?  I'm breaking MVVM in that way because there isn't another way to get the view associated with something that's dynamically loaded into another view.

Comment: don't bind views. load the corresponding VM into the content of the contentcontrol and let the contentcontrol decide the proper view for its content.

Comment: How would it do that when the xaml for that content comes from the same source as the view model?

Comment: `xaml for that content comes from the same source as the view model` you can bind as many views as you want to the same VM source. it's not like those contents are supposed to be related to each other. they are representations of the same source which happen to be look-alikes.

Comment: OK I have VM a, b and c in import.dll (loaded using the addin architecture) as well as views x, y, and z.  How does the mainview know which view to use for vm a, considering that main.dll is late bound to import.dll due to the use of addins.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to store the items source as a private value in the ReportParameter, and internally to the control bind to that internal value rather than the bound external value.

The reason for this is that WPF discards and re-creates the UI every time the combobox item is changed.  Thus causing the items source to be set to nothing, which subsequently sets a null value into the selected value.